# sistema de inventario

Tags: c++

Me podrían decir si el código esta bien por favor, si compila todo bien y eso, pero no se si la manera en la que esta desarrollado es el correcto...

Me podrían ayudar a crear la opción para eliminar un producto, intente de varias maneras y no me sirve

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Registro{
    char nombre[50];
    int codigo;
}registro;


void registro_productos();
void ver_productos(Registro);
void menu();


int main(){

    menu();
    getch();
    return 0;
}


void registro_productos(){
    cout<<"Ingre Nombre: ";
    cin>>registro.nombre;
    cout<<"ingrese Codigo :";
    cin>>registro.codigo;
}


void ver_productos(Registro){
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<registro.nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Codigo: "<<registro.codigo;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

necesito una para poder eliminar un producto

```
void menu(){
    int opcion;
    cout<<"1.registro productos"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.ver productos"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.eliminar producto"<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;
    system("cls");
    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            registro_productos();
            system("pause");
            return menu();
        break;
        case 2:
            ver_productos(registro);
            system("pause");
            return menu();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida Ana, te recomiento que entres a [ask] y posteriormente edites o elimines tu pregunta según corresponda... Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones y puede llevarte a tener puntuaciones negativas o reportes...

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a realizar el [tour] para que entiendas un poco cómo funcionamos. Tu pregunta sería mejor recibida si colocas el código de lo que has intentado por tu cuenta (aunque esté mal). Aquí te ayudaremos con gusto a resolver tu problema, pero debes mostrar que lo has intentado. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos